# How to run ".js" file in node as esmodule without setting type in package.json or changing the extension

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I'm determined to find a way to do this. Here's why:

I'm writing tests for `.js` files which are bundled with webpack for a browser client.
I would like to run these tests in nodejs. There is a "build.js" script which is NOT using es6 modules, it's a commonjs module - so updating `package.json` would break it.

Is there a way to do this or is everything fundamentally broken?

Edit: after my workaround it *still* doesn't really work 'cause now webpack is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Node `v21.1.0`, see [release](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v21.1.0).

You can use `--experimental-detect-module` flag, which eliminates the requirement for `"type":` in `package.json` or the use of `.mjs/.cjs` extensions.

Comment: Marking as accepted answer as this experimental feature seems completely reasonable to me and I hope it becomes default; if there's ambiguity it means either the file doesn't have any import statements or require calls - so it doesn't matter what it's detected as - or it's neither a valid CJS module nor a valid ESM. This puts the responsibility of ensuring consistency of import mechanisms onto linters, which is where I would prefer that responsibility to lie since it's not build-breaking if the tool doesn't understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a subdirectory with its own `package.json` that has `"type": "module"` set, so that it doesn't break any commonjs scripts outside of it but everything inside can import other es6 modules.

So yes, everything is fundamentally broken but there is a workaround.

Comment: Just here to say yes, it is broken, it is not just you.